# Issue with JMS Listener in Sun Java App Server

Tags: jms, listener, jcaps

I am running a listener program on a JMS queue hosted in Sun Java System Application Server 9.1_02 (build b08-p03)

After receiving a message I will extract and log some details in to a log file.

I observed that when running listener for really long hours, it stops receiving messages. I had to manually stop the program and start it again. Then it receives some 200-300 message and then stops again. I had to restart it to retrieve another set of messages.

Why is this weird behavior? Can someone throw light on this?

Thank you
Chaitanya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue myself. I am running the listener as Load Runner Java Vuser script. One negative thing about LR is that it does not show any exceptions. The script appears to be running but it actually does nothing. I found this when I ported the script to Eclipse and found that the script is throwing exceptions. This is essentially because I am not checking for a certain condition.

Happy that I demystified at last!

Thanks.